# Several localizations yet still showing English only

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I decided to merge several of my projects into one project using the same code base and use different targets for the different versions of my application.

My application is translated to 7 languages with English as default. The other languages are: Swedish, Dutch, German, French, Polish and Spanish. The translations worked like a charm before. I am using the `NSLocalizedString` and have my `Localizable.strings` which is translated. 
However, now that I merged my projects together, and also added the `InfoPlist.strings` file, the application incists on using the default texts (English). When I start the application and get the "share location" question, I get the question in the localized language (So the OS does get the localization), but the rest of the application is still in English.

The files are correctly translation and have no errors. I have tested several languages, but all are in English. 
If I set the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to e.g. `Swedish`, the whole app is in Swedish instead. So the localizations work, but the app ignores the system setting.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to Clean project and rebuild app after that.

Comment: did that maybe a 100 times as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I have several strings files, one for my app translation, and one for each target called `InfoPlist.strings` which contains just `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName` for localized app name. These cannot be included into the `Localizable.strings` since these are different for each target.

I removed the `InfoPlist.strings` files from my project and now the app is localized again.