# iOS Localization on a per target basis?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I have a single project which builds multiple Apps on a per target basis, in order to localize the Apps I can add localization languages to the project, but not on a per target basis. Meaning that any target we build will appear to support all localizations for the project. i.e. Target A must support English and French, but Target B must only support English.

Is there any way to add a localization language on a per target basis? Or is the correct way to do this, to branch the project and maintain different branches of the codebase with different localizations for different targets?

Comment: How are you using localization ? using iOS setting change language option or you have select language option at app startup etc.

Comment: The requirement is to use the iOS settings 'change language' option, and thus the built in support for localization. I suppose implementing a custom localization framework would allow for per target based localization. You do lose the ability to localize NIB files and images nicely in xcode doing that though.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523792/localized-project-with-several-targets-with-localized-app-names).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
+ NSString* NSCustomLocalizedString( NSString *key , NSString *comment)
{
NSString *rs = nil;

#ifdef A //target A
    //you define English-French
    rs = NSLocalizedString(key,@"");
#else  //target B
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-en",nil);
return rs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the localizable.strings files for the language you need to remove from a target.
2. Then remove the target membership for the selected files.