# Localizing InfoPlist.strings per build target

Tags: xcode, localizable.strings

I'm creating two separate apps from the same Xcode project and they need slightly different wording for their respective location usage descriptions.

In essence I would like to have separate `InfoPlist.strings` files for each of my build targets, but it seems I cannot simply create `InfoPlist-A.strings` and `InfoPlist-B.strings` and check them to only belong to the appropriate targets. (Target B simply doesn't seem to find its strings file, and thus disables all location services in absence of the usage description.)

I also want to localize the descriptions so it's not enough to simply word them differently in the targets' respective `Info.plist` files.

Is there any way to tell Xcode "here's the strings file you should look at for this target" or is it all just opaque magic based on a fixed file name?

Comment: I think this SO question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507240/several-localizations-yet-still-showing-english-only

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan on having one App name for your project then I recommend placing the file in the same directory as your Localizable.strings file.  However, if you have multiple targets and some of them use different app names then you will want to create a separate directory for the InfoPlist.strings file.  You will then need to create a separate InfoPlist.strings file for each app name and associate it with the correct target. (https://kitefaster.com/2016/06/29/how-to-localize-an-apps-name-with-infoplist-strings/)

My Project:
[Two InfoPlist.strings files in different directory and belong to different targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuFwm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by sharing comm `localizable.strings` files and with separate `InfoPlist.Strings` for each target。
few steps:

1. remove the `InfoPlist.Strings` from the directory where it locates(typically inside your `zh-Hans.lproj`, `en.lproj`,... directories), keep the `Localizable.strings` files where they are, and assign it to all targets you wish to.
2. Create a new `InfoPlist.Strings` file IN A NEW DIRECTORY YOU CREATED and assign it to the target you as you wish
3. Create another `InfoPlist.Strings` file in ANOTHER new directory and assign it to the new target.